# Can polymorphism be influenced with Interfaces

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm trying to override a very small bit of code in a service using dependency injection. Unfortunately the existing class that I want to override was not implemented using the `virtual` keyword so I cannot override the method directly. The class and interface in the library look something like this:

```
//NOTE: I CANNOT ALTER ANY OF THIS CODE IT'S IN THE LIBRARY
public interface IService
{
    string DoWork(); //Actual name doesn't matter
}

public class DefaultService : IService
{
    public string DoWork() { return "Default Service result"; }
}
```

In my code I'd like to override default service so that I can extend it's `DoWork` result so I tried this:

```
public class MyService : DefaultService
{
    public new string DoWork() { return base.DoWork() + " some more words"; }
}
```

Now through some experimentation it's clear that this doesn't actually achieve the desired effect.

```
public static void Main()
{
    IService serv = new MyService();
    Console.WriteLine(serv.DoWork()); // Prints: "Default Service result"
}
```

So is there a pattern I can follow that will allow me to use the entirety of `DefaultService` without having to completely reimplement it with my small additions?

Comment: You could look at the [decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern)

Comment: `public class MyService : DefaultService, IService`

Comment: @Gusman I've tried that but it produces the same result

Comment: No it does not,, just tested it

Comment: @Gusman I tried it on https://dotnetfiddle.net/ I'll try it again in my actual environment

Comment: What's wrong in making `DefaultService`'s `DoWork` method virtual and override it in `MyService`.

Comment: @dcg as i noted in my question I did not write `DefaultService` it's a part of a library.

Comment: Beware that will only work if you cast it to `IService`, if you cast it to `DefaultService` obviously will call the base implementation

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/TtuLR

Comment: @Gusman my understandings of how the library works under the hood is that it uses the interface for everything so that should work for my purposes assuming i can get it to work. I'll comment again once I've tested it

Comment: I think you are assuming too much, for what you say they are casting to the base implementation in some parts and to the interface in others, the interface is solved with the definition I pasted, but the base definition is not modifiable

Comment: @Gusman that totally works if you want to add it as an answer i'll accept it. apparently dotnetfiddle.net is not as reliable a source as i hoped.

Comment: @Gusman also i may not have made this clear in my question but the library depends very heavily on dependency injection and using interfaces over concrete implemenations so I'm pretty certain the interface is used everywhere underneath the hood. I'll keep a close eye on this in case and your caveat is appreciated.

Comment: Full disclosure i went back and looked at my dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/8SrzGM and realized i made a typo which i have since fixed. dotnetfiddle does in fact behave correctly for this i just mistyped the variable name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the inheritance to the interface, as the class will implement it explicitly, when you cast the instance to the interface it will use the new functions:

```
public interface IService
{
    string DoWork(); //Actual name doesn't matter
}

public class DefaultService : IService
{
    public string DoWork() { return "Default Service result"; }
}

public class MyService : DefaultService, IService
{
    public new string DoWork() { return base.DoWork() + " some more words"; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this is a bit rough.
You could look at the decorator pattern

```
Decorator : IService
{
     IService _service
     Public Decorator(IService service)
     {
           _service = service
     }

     public string DoWork()
     {
          //new code
          _service.DoWork()
         //new code
     }
}
```

And then

```
IService service = new Decoration(new MyService)
```

Comment: I think decorators are usually abstract and then you have derived classes. But yes this is a valid approach.  Very similar to this would be *encapsulation*, but you wouldn't take a service as a constructor param, and instead construct it internally. The big disadvantage to both these approaches is if you want it to look like inheritance, you need to implement all the other public methods of the base class and proxy the calls.  `public string OtherMethod() { return _service.OtherMethod(); }` which can be overwhelming and a bit of a maintenance headache.

Comment: Yeah in this particular case there are a bunch of other methods that I would have to do this for to expose them. I just didn't include them in my example. Still this is a perfectly valid approach. +1

Comment: I think you could use T4 templates to generate some of  the code but can be a pain if there are lots of methods that dont need decorating

Comment: An another possible alternative could possibly be an IoC container like ninject, or an AOP framework that can set up interceptors.